# Как делегировать обработку события не с селектором, а с Jquery объектом?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно обработать событие для динамически добавленного объекта.
Обработка обычно делается так:

```
$parent.on(events, [selector], [data], handler)
```

Где:

- `$parent` — это статический родительский элемент
- `selector` — это селектор для выбора нужного дочернего элемента

Допустим, нужный дочерний элемент, событие на котором нужно обработать, уже хранится в переменной `$child`:

```
$parent.on(events, $child, [data], handler)
```

Так не работает. Как делегировать обработку в таком случае?

Answer (score 0):

```
$parent.on("event_name", function(event) {
  if (event.target == $child[0]) {
    // ... do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

По идее, стоит не делегировать событие а назначить его прямо на враппер, и на нем уже определять от кого из дочерних элементов оно пришло.
Если пришло от дочки, которая имеет нужный класс (ведь дочек много может быть разных), то это то, что нужно.

```
var $wrapper = $("#wrapper");
    $inners = $(".inner") || ""

$wrapper.click(function(e){
  if ( $(e.target).hasClass("inner") ){
    alert("Inner click");
  }
})
```

Вот работающая модель, может пригодится )
https://codepen.io/Valiev/pen/gzvZVJ